# Equal height column not adding padding

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to equal column height but its not calculating padding in it and so text going out of the div.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //set the starting bigestHeight variable
            var biggestHeight = 0;
            //check each of them
            $('.equal').each(function(){
                //if the height of the current element is
                //bigger then the current biggestHeight value
                if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){
                    //update the biggestHeight with the
                    //height of the current elements
                    biggestHeight = $(this).height();
                }
            });
            //when checking for biggestHeight is done set that
            //height to all the elements
            $('.equal').height(biggestHeight);

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `.outerHeight()`

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

- `.height()` = Height
- `.outerHeight()` = Height + Padding + Border
- `.outerHeight(true)` = Height + Padding + Border + Margin

If you have images inside your elements you should just wait for the images have been loaded using `$(window).load()`

```
    $(window).load(function(){ // wait for all content and images are loaded
        var biggestHeight = 0;
        $('.equal').each(function(){
            if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){
                biggestHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        });
        $('.equal').height(biggestHeight);
    });
```

Comment: I believe your guideline is promising but not easy to understand for beginner like me. So this is my request if you can give me some example with my code.

Comment: @pixelngrain might be you just need to wait for images to load . look at my edited answer

Comment: It does the same thing like my code. Not considering padding in it. Any idea?